# How to hide not rendered php code?

Tags: php, email

Here's the question. I have some kind of php script. and then html
like this:

```
<?
foreach($_POST as $name=>$val){
        $body .= $name." : ".$val."\n";
    }
    mail("someemail@e.com","title",$body);
}   
?>
```

So, when this code executes successfully, everything is fine.
But when code does not execute(for example if I do not have smtp server), then I got this on my html page: `$val){ $body .= $name." : ".$val."\n"; } mail("someemail@e.com","title",$body); } ?>`

How do I hide this code, so it does not show on my page? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible that the server does not have the short opening tag enabled.

At the top of the file, use `<?php` instead of just `<?`.

You should do this in any case where you do not control the server that your code will run on.

Answer (score 2):

The code would not show up just because you don't have an SMTP server.  The only reasons it would appear are

1. If the server doesn't have PHP installed
2. Apache isn't configured properly
3. The file doesn't have an extension of `.php`
4. Or you're not viewing the file through the server.

Comment: I am testing it locally with xampp. It does render other code fine though. it is .php it does have PHP installed and I am vieweing it through the server. So, what Apache settingas should I change? Thanks

Comment: Then it may be as Charles mentioned, you need to use `<?php`.  You really should anyway.